# Как в паттерне Observer (Наблюдатель) сделать подписку на разные типы событий?

Tags: java, mvc, шаблоны-проектирования, события

Как реализовать, что почитать на данную тему?

- нужно подписываться на различные типы событий
- на каждый тип - свой метод слушатель

Нужно что то  вроде этого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Буду благодарен любым идеям / ссылкам !

Comment: Посмотрите библиотеки реализации Publisher/Subscriber. И помните, что обсервабл отмечен deprecated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы получить то, что вам нужно, нужна реализация Observer, которая в методе notify (оповещение) принимает аргумент, который должен указывать на тип события.

Класс Observer должен иметь примерно следующий вид:

`void addListener(EventType, callback)`, где EventType - некоторый тип возможного события, а Callback - тип делегата с нужным вам прототипом (например `void (EventType eventType, object data)`).

`void notify(EventType, object data)`, где EventType - тип оповещаемых событий, data - сами данные.

Сами же слушатели могут храниться в таком формате:

`Map<EventType, List<Callback>> listeners;`

После чего, мы в notify() получаем из Map конкретный тип слушателей по ключу и проходим по ним в цикле и вызываем зарегистрированных слушателей через callback.

Другой вариант:

На каждый тип событий создать по Observer и в методе addListener уже делать маршрутизацию (в какой Observer добавить слушателя).

Comment: Спасибо! Решил следующим образом: Custom_EventObject(Object source, Enum eventType, Enum event)